# electron webview uploadfile error net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I have upgraded electron app to 9.x
I am loading a site using electron webview.
After upgrade when i am trying to upload file I am getting below error:

net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

works fine with electron 8.x and lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

This was problem with electron 9 version
I upgraded it to electron 10 and file upload error was fixed.